# Bootstrap 4: How to have a full width navbar with the content in a container (Like the SO Navbar)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.

How do I make a navbar like the SO navbar?

With the content aligned like a "container" but the width of a "container-fluid" in bootstrap 4?

I want the width of the "fixed-top" navbar setting without it being fixed-top and the navbar content in a "container".

I would provide an example but I'm trying to make something exactly like the navbar at the top of this page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap an element around the `.container` element.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

#primary-nav {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary-nav">

  <div class="container">
  
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>    
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 34):

I was able to get the menu to 100% width

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

using **nav-fill w-100** with Bootstrap 4

Comment: this resolved my issue and is clearer than the container wrapping

Comment: +1 for w-100. This is the way to go when you are trying to fill the menu items inside the navbar. nav-fill only is not enough.

Answer (score 14):

I had met this issue also. I solved by put the `<nav>...</nav>` outside the `<div class='container'>...</div>` or `<div class='container-fluid'>...</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer from @ravi.ram but it did not work for me. Here is how my code starts. Note the nav is outside the container. Solution is below the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
              <img src="images/logo.jpg">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
```

Here are few ways that worked.

1. If you want to keep `container` then you can use inline style like this. `<div class="container" style="max-width:100%;">` This is because the `container` has a max-width set to 1140px.
2. Use `container-fluid` instead of `container`
3. Dont use the `container` at all. Remove the `div` completely.

Also see https://codepen.io/nishitmistry/pen/VwwozwL

Answer (score 0):

you can try by just changing nav class to `class="navbar navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top"`, you will get full width navbar.