# Custom styles not proper applied while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a webpage using both bootstrap and my own styles for css. When I try to change some of my styles, bootstrap seems to override some of them, such as removing line from nav bar or making the nav bar be full width. I am currently using the solution from: [Bootstrap 4: How to have a full width navbar with the content in a container (Like the SO Navbar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622790/bootstrap-4-how-to-have-a-full-width-navbar-with-the-content-in-a-container-li) to make the nav into a full width.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Cuppela</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="main_nav">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="menu_container" style="max-width:100%;">
            <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
h1{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 85px;
    color: black;
  }

body{
  margin: 0px;
}

#main_nav {
 background-color: #333;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
```

I am currently using Bootstrap 4.3.1 .

Comment: did you try to set your styles to  !important state

Comment: Hi, wouldn't setting styles to !important affect the whole flow of the css?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use css classes to overwrite styles instead of targetting html elements. This also gives us scope to improve [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of CSS classes which is the best alternative to !important.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to apply important to your css elements.

```
h1{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    font-size: 85px !important;
    color: black !important;
  }

body{
  margin: 0px !important;
}

#main_nav {
 background-color: #333 !important;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  background-color: #333 !important;
}

li {
  float: left !important;
}

li a {
  display: block !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  padding: 14px 16px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900 !important;
}
```